# Как в type struct задать функцию в Golang?

Tags: golang

```
type Teste struct {
    Text string
    Function func()
}
func Hello(vk *api.VK, obj events.MessageNewObject, dbpool *sql.DB) ...
```

Как мне вызывать

```
Teste{
    Text: "привет",
    Function: ...Hello(vk, db, obj)
}
```

? (cannot use Hello (type func(*"github.com/SevereCloud/vksdk/api".VK, events.MessageNewObject, *sql.DB)) as type func(*"github.com/SevereCloud/vksdk/v2/api".VK, events.MessageNewObject, *sql.DB) in field value)

Если что, функция Hello находится в другом файле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, чего вы хотите, то по идее нужно как-то так делать:

```
Teste{
    Text: "привет",
    Function: func() { Hello(vk, db, obj) },
}
```